# Web site Deployment Error

Tags: asp.net, deployment, assemblies

I'm getting the following error on website deployment.

> Could not load file or assembly
>   'eWorld.UI, Version=2.0.6.2393,
>   Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=24d65337282035f2' or
>   one of its dependencies

I have added the eWorld.UI.dll to the bin folder also. So what could be the reason for the error?

EDIT

#

It looks like not only the above assembly application does not referring to any assembly in my bin folder.

Comment: I think we're going to need a lot more information thatn just that. We need to know the process of how you're trying to do and some basic info on what software you're using and server architecture. the `eWorld.UI.dll` implies this could be a Windows IIS server?

Comment: You can use the Fusion Log Viewer to diagnose this issue : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4(v=vs.71).aspx. It logs Assembly binding failures for your analysis, and should tell you exactly which assembly it's not finding.

Answer (score 0):

Does the eWorld.UI.dll have some other dependency that is missing on the production server? This happens from time to time and it usually is resolved by adding the missing dll to the bin folder, just as you have done, and then restart the Application Pool (if using IIS).